# MaterializeCSS Icons not working

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm having an issue with getting the icons to display while using MaterializeCSS. I'm using the bare bones "Getting Started" from the documentation but for whatever reason icons refuse to show up. Below is the code I'm using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
   <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
   <!--Import materialize.css-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">
   <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed">
            <li class="bold"><a href="#!" class="waves-effect waves-teal">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
            <li class="bold"><a href="#!" class="">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
            <li class="no-padding">
                <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
                    <li>
                        <a class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-teal">Dropdown<i class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down"></i></a>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#!">First</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!">Second</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!">Third</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#!">Fourth</a></li>
                            </ul>
                         </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
  </nav>
  <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.button-collapse').sideNav({
        menuWidth: 300, // Default is 240
        closeOnClick: true // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
    });
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

All this code is trying to do is display a navbar, it was pulled directly from the documentation.

The hamburger menu doesn't appear when the browser is resized
[image: No Hamburger Icon]

The dropdown arrow doesn't appear beside the dropdown menu item. 
[image: Dropdown Missing]

I feel like it's something stupid that I'm missing but I've been looking at it for 2 hours and my brain is melted. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** Here's the updated code for the dropdown arrow too:

```
<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
```

I ran into this issue too and wondered where my hamburger icon went!

Unfortunately, a lot of their documentation hasn't been refreshed, so the code you are using is a bit outdated.

Change this:

```
<i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i>
```

to this:

```
<i class="material-icons">menu</i>
```

and you should see the icon. If you check their source code, you'll see that even their site uses the updated code that's different from their docs:

[image: MaterializeCSS Source Code for Menu Icon]

Comment: Hey! No problem. Glad I could help! :) Check out my edit too!

Comment: That's great, thanks. Do you know if there's a list of these updated icon names or are you just checking source code to find them?

Comment: I've been working with the framework for a while and found that any time there's an "mdl" prefix in a class, I would remove the whole mdl class (ex. "mdl-navigation-menu") and replace with just the "material-icons" class. Then use their [icons](https://design.google.com/icons/) page to find the icon you need. In this case, that page IS up-to-date!

Comment: Great stuff, I've just started working with it and it is a nice change from working with Bootstrap, I'll have to keep in mind they don't keep their documentation up to date! Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem! I'm really happy I could help. And yes, I LOVE it compared to Bootstrap. Much cleaner and more my style.

Answer (score 0):

CHANGE **HTTP** TO **HTTPS** in linking font library. It worked for me.